# Jmeter array Response, getting the sum and extracting Part2

Tags: api, jmeter, response

I want to get the sum of values parameters and multiply by 3,

{
"timestamps": "2021-04-15T11:39:00Z",
"properties": [{
"values": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"name": "Value.Restricted",
"type": "Long"
}],
"progress": 100.0
}

Kindly see attached file for your reference. Thank you so much in advance

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/565qL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get the sum of these `values` attribute you can use [JSON JMESPath Extractor](http://$%7B__jexl3(($%7Bsum%7D%20*%203).intValue(),)%7D), example query:

   ```
   sum(properties[0].values)
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]
2. If you want to multiply it by 3 - it can be done using i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3):

   ```
   ${__jexl3((${sum} * 3),)}
   ```

   it will return floating point number like `10.0` if you need just `10` - call `intValue()` chain function

   ```
   ${__jexl3((${sum} * 3).intValue(),)}
   ```

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much